# How to count number of entries satisfying specific case?

Tags: matlab

```
A=[1 2 3 4 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
   0 1 2 3 4 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
   0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0; 
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5;
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 0 0 0 0 0;
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 0 0 0 0 0];
```

What is code to count number "1" in the column which only has elements which have value greater than 1 and less than 4.

note: zeros is ignored.

Thus, My expected output is `res = 1` which is in second column only.

Here is what I tried:

```
res = sum( sum(A(2 :end,all(A>1&A<4))==1, 2),1 );
```

but zeros are still being counted in my code.

Comment: I can't figure out what you want... won't the count of '1's in columns which have only values greater than one and less than four always be zero? If you meant inclusive, in your example you have four different columns that match, all with a value of one. We need more information.

Comment: @xxbbcc look at my updated post

Comment: It is still not clear to me what you want. The number of "1" in a column with values between 1 and 4 (not including 1 and 4) is always zero!?

Comment: Can you update your question indicating which column(s) match your criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you could do it this way:

Start by finding all columns that violate the first rule that elements of `A` my not be greater than 4

`[~, del, ~] = find(A>=4)`

Remove those columns:

`A(:, unique(del)) = []`

Which gives:

```
 A =
 1     2     3     0     0     0     0     0
 0     1     2     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     1     2     3
 0     0     0     2     3     0     0     0
 0     0     0     2     3     0     0     0
```

Now we find all remaining columns that have a `1`:

`[~, c1, ~] = find(A == 1);`

And all columns that have at least one value greater than `1` following the second requirement:

`[~, c2, ~] = find(A > 1)`

These vectors `c1` and `c2` with the column numbers we then simply intersect and count:

`numel(intersect(c1, c2))`

Now there are plenty of Matlab wizards on this forum, and my instinct tells me there is a better answer, so perhaps you should wait a bit.